# How to make a 2D phase portrait of 3 non-linear differential equations?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot phase portrait of a nonlinear systems using this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp, odeint
alpha=0.565
beta=0.002 
delta=2 
eta=0.1 
mu1=0.2
mu2=0.2
gamma1=0.05
gamma2=0.04
xi=1.05
def dynamical_model_tumor(X,t):
    x, y, z = X
    dxdt = alpha*x*(1-beta*x)-delta*x*y+eta*x*z
    dydt = x*y-mu1*y-gamma1*y+gamma2*z
    dzdt = xi*x*z-mu2*z+gamma1*y-gamma2*z 
    return [dxdt,dydt,dzdt]
print(dynamical_model_tumor([50,50,50],0))  
x0=np.array([
      [0.3, 0.3, 0.3],
      [0.3, 0.9, 0.8],
      [0.3, 0.3, 0.9],
      [0.3, 0.9, 0.3],
      [0.9, 0.3, 0.3],
      [0.8, 0.7, 0.9],
      [0.3, 0.4, 0.7],
      [0.5, 0.05, 0.5],
      [0.5, 0.05, 1],
      [0.5, 1, 1]])
t=np.linspace(0,30,8000)
sol=[ odeint(dynamical_model_tumor,init,t) for init in x0];
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
for k in range(len(x0)):
    x,y,z=sol[k].T
    ax.plot(x,y,z,'b', lw=2)
plt.show(); plt.close()
```

The result is [PhasePortrait3D](https://postimg.cc/pytD0WTt)

How can I get the phase portrait in 2D like this: [PhasePortrait2D](https://postimg.cc/zL7FW4Cg)?